# How can I create a script with multi command

Tags: command-line, script, desktop

I tried to create a script on OS X. I do something wrong.
I want to execute 2 command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool true
```

and

```
killall Finder
```

I saved and chmod the file but I got some errors:

```
/Users/max/Desktop/visible.command ; exit;
MacBook-Pro-de-Maxime:~ max$ /Users/max/Desktop/visible.command ; exit;
/Users/max/Desktop/visible.command: line 1: {rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1343cocoasubrtf160: command not found
/Users/max/Desktop/visible.command: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/Users/max/Desktop/visible.command: line 2: `{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;\f1\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}'
logout
```

[image: output]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: obviously your script has "rtfiansiansicpg1252cocoartf1343cocoasubrtfr160" line at line 1. You should save your script a plain text file. Did you use TextEdit or Pages to save your command file? This could be the reason.

Answer (score 3):

You have saved your file as a Rich Text Format file (.rtf)

In TextEdit.app

Open your file and use the Make Plain Text menu to change it to the correct format for coding.

Using anything other than plan text will mean that the file includes formatting code  for styles and such that is visible to the shell layer but not to the user when viewing the file.

For example.

Rich Text Format file with the extension changed is still a rich text file

[image]

---

Reading it from the command line.

`$ cat foo.command`

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1344\cocoasubrtf720
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red43\green39\blue19;\red234\green234\blue234;\red37\green127\blue159;
}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720

\f0\fs26 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
defaults write com.apple.finder \cf4 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
CreateDesktop\cf2 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
 -bool true}
```

---

Change to plain text and re saved.

[image]

---

[image]

---

Read from the command line.

```
$ cat foo.command
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool true
```

( examples are for illustration only and not how to do the actual coding)

Answer (score -1):

If you're just needing to run any two commands via a script, you can just create something like this, open a text editor and add:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo foo && echo bar
```

Save it as foo.sh, then:

```
$ sh ./foo.sh
foo
bar
```

The `&&` lets you have two commands being executed, one after another, or you can just put the commands on different lines.

In your case, replace `echo foo` with `defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool true` and replace `echo bar` with `killall Finder`. You'll probably need to run `foo.sh` with elevated priveleges using `$ sudo sh ./foo.sh` since you are changing defaults and killing pids.

You may have to make it executable, too:

`chmod +x foo.sh`

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409946/how-do-i-make-this-file-sh-executable-via-double-click

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted your answer. Obviously the topicstarter already knows that making a text file with commands will take him to the goal and asks why his actions did not work out. Your answer is not informative for this reason. Also, (sorry, being too picky) mentioning things like "pid" to someone who struggles to save a text file will not work out.

Comment: @Rilakkuma 
OP states:
"How can i create a script" and "I want to execute 2 command"

`&&` executes two commands, and I gave an example of running it in a script. How is that NOT an answer to his question?

Comment: Not going to argue over this, but there's one more line: "I saved and chmod the file but I got some errors".

Comment: So how does giving more examples of doing what the OP is trying to do not help him get to a solution?